# Cast ListView Items to List<string>?

Tags: c#, winforms, listviewitem

How can I cast `ListView.Items` to a `List<string>`?

This is what I tried:

```
List<string> list = lvFiles.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

but I received this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to type 'System.String'.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A `ListViewItemCollection` is exactly what it sounds like - a collection of `ListViewItem` elements. It's *not* a collection of strings. Your code fails at execution time for the same reason that this code would fail at compile time:

```
ListViewItem item = lvFiles.Items[0];
string text = (string) item; // Invalid cast!
```

If you want a list of strings, each of which is taken from the `Text` property of a `ListViewItem`, you can do that easily:

```
List<string> list = lvFiles.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                 .Select(item => item.Text)
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Why i can only see the files name instead of the whole path ?

Comment: @user2214609: I have no idea, given that we didn't even know that the `ListView` contained filenames. It sounds like you should ask that as a separate question - the contents of the `Text` property on a `ListViewItem` which is populated with a filename is a *very* different matter from converting a collection of `ListViewItem` values to a `List<string>`.

Comment: What can i do if i don't have Cast or any LINQ functions at all ? (WinForm project)

Comment: @user1803300: *Why* would you not have LINQ?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't have these LINQ ext methods in my WinForm project, it's only available in WPF, what can i do?

Comment: @user1803300: Um, no, LINQ has nothing to do with WPF. So long as you're targeting .NET 3.5 or higher, it should be fine. Make sure you have a `using` directive for `System.Linq`.

Comment: Cast no longer exists.

Comment: @Switch: It really, really does. I suspect you just don't have a `using` directive for `System.Linq`, as per the comment from November 2015.

Answer (score 5):

The `Cast` method will essentially try to perform a box/unbox, so it will fail if the items in the list aren't already strings. Try this instead:

```
List<string> list = lvFiles.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Or this

```
List<string> list = lvFiles.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                 .Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

Comment: Won't your first example give you a list where every element is the string "System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem" ?

Comment: Looks like it will give "ListViewItem: {text here}"

Comment: @AdamV I'm not sure off the top of my head what `ListViewItem.ToString` will return (which is why I gave the alternate solution). `ListViewItem` does [override `ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9syath98.aspx) so I assume it does something a little more than just return it's own type name.

Comment: Why i can only see the files name instead of the whole path ?

Comment: Cast no longer exists.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this

```
List<string> list = lvFiles.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x=> x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Cast no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using the `Select` method:

for list text:

```
List<string> listText = lvFiles.Items.Select(item => item.Text).ToList();
```

for list values:

```
List<string> listValues = lvFiles.Items.Select(item => item.Value).ToList();
```

Or maybe, for both:

```
Dictionary<string, string> files = lvFiles.Items.ToDictionary(key => key.Value, item => item.Text);
```