# ListView with two columns to dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, listview, dictionary

I have a `ListView` with two columns (*nameColumn* and *typeColumn*). I want to create a dictionary (specifically, `Dictionary<string, string>`) with *nameColumn*'s values as the dictionary keys and the *typeColumn*'s values as the dictionary values.

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932873/cast-listview-items-to-liststring) question (one column to `List<string>`) and googled it, but didn't understand how to accomplish exactly what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: @Usman - I only set the `ListView` properties with the designer... There is not code written by me.

Comment: This is not an Off-Topic question. I am asking HOW to write a certain code that I didn't manage to write myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
var dictionary = yourListView.Items
                             .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                             .ToDictionary(item => item.SubItems[0].Text, 
                                           item => item.SubItems[1].Text);
```

Do note that this will fail if your listview includes data with duplicate keys.

Comment: I get this error: `'ListView.ListViewItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and no extension method 'ToDictionary' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView.ListViewItemCollection' could be found`

Comment: @Sipo Add the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: @sipo sorry didn't remember `Items` returns an `IEnumerable`, not an `IEnumerable<T>`. Now it should work.