# The argument type 'List<Null>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter

I want to create a chat for my application. I need to display the name field of all users I have in my users collection in firebase using flutter.
The following image is similar to what I am trying to do.

[[image: 1]]

Here is my code :

```
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text("You have no contact.");
            }
            return ListView (
              children: snapshot.data?.docs.map(
                (doc){ 
                  new Text(doc["fullName"]);
                  }
              ).toList(), // all the children is making an error
            );
          }
        )
```

And here is the problem I have : `The argument type 'List<Null>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.`.

I guess the problem comes from my snapshot which isn't wrapped in a Widget, but the code I took inspiration from did the same thing and doesn't seem to have any problem.
Their code : `return ListView( children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document){}).toList(),`

Has anyone any idea ? Thank you for reading me

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/17932913/740553 help answer this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yes and no, it helps me to see where the error could come from but it's C# unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your function with block body but you are not using return command to return the widget!

Fix it by returning the Text widget:

```
            return ListView (
              children: snapshot.data?.docs.map(
                (doc){ 
                  return new Text(doc["fullName"]);
                  }
              ).toList(), // all the children is making an error
            );
```

You can also replace the block body with an arrow fucntion:

```
            return ListView (
              children: snapshot.data?.docs.map(
                (doc) => 
                   new Text(doc["fullName"])
              ).toList(), // all the children is making an error
            );
```

##### FIX: if you are facing with error

```
The argument type 'List<Text>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'
```

then cast the list to a `List<Widget>`:

```
snapshot.data?.docs.map(
                (doc) => 
                   new Text(doc["fullName"])
              ).toList() as List<Widget>
```

Comment: Thanks it was actually logical, thank you for helping me !
Now I have the problem ```The argument type 'List<Text>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'``` but I will try to take care of it later
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @chubbymarschmallow i've  updated my answer, try it

Comment: If you switch from fat arrow to a regular function body you need to add a return ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

one of the solutions is to add type  to the map method.

```
ListView (
          children: snapshot.data?.docs.map<Widget>(
            (doc){ 
              new Text(doc["fullName"]);
              }
          ).toList(), // all the children is making an error
        );
```